# Get productID with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, url, beautifulsoup

The website is: [https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/玩美日記-水絲布面膜-25mL-玻尿酸-蘋果多酚-膠原胜月太-p066283079496](https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/%E7%8E%A9%E7%BE%8E%E6%97%A5%E8%A8%98-%E6%B0%B4%E7%B5%B2%E5%B8%83%E9%9D%A2%E8%86%9C-25mL-%E7%8E%BB%E5%B0%BF%E9%85%B8-%E8%98%8B%E6%9E%9C%E5%A4%9A%E9%85%9A-%E8%86%A0%E5%8E%9F%E8%83%9C%E6%9C%88%E5%A4%AA-p066283079496)

I want to get its id (eg:PXXXXXXXXX). I've tried several different approaches with BeautifulSoup, including a different html parser, but none of these have been successful.
Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>商品編號：<span itemprop="productID">p066283079496</span></li>
    <li>店家貨號：RTMK069C</li>
    <li>購買人次：136</li>
    <li>銷售件數：1337</li>
</ul>
```

I have done this:

```
class AppleCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
name ='apple'
start_urls = ['https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/152982163-category.html?img_only=0&sort_by=[rank]&order_by=0']
def parse(self, response):
    res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    for news in res.select('.P-18'):
        yield scrapy.Request(news.select('a')[0]['href'],self.parse_detail)            
def parse_detail(self, response):
    res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    print res.select('h1')[0].text
    print ID# HOW?
    print res.select('.price')[0].text,res.select('.store')[0].text
```

Comment: Why do you need `BeautifulSoup` in your Scrapy spider? Scrapy itself is powerful in terms of locating elements, simply use `response.xpath()` and `response.css()`.

Comment: But you have the productID in url?!

Comment: I know I have ID in its URL, but I want to try it in <span itemprop ...>. All in all, thank you for your suggestion.Is that means BeautifulSoup does not have any help?